# IComparer<T> implementation trouble for sorting a List<T>

Tags: c#

I'm having some trouble creating my own List structure. I'm trying to create a List structure called SortedList. The objective is for it to Sort its items as soon as add a new item. This list will not get too big in  the project I'm using it for (maybe 50-100 items at most). However, I was testing by adding a simple item of class Employee which has a Name property. And I want this SortedList to sort on employee's Name.

Here is my attempt.

The Employee class

```
public class Employee : IComparer<Employee>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee()
    {
    }

    public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.Name, y.Name,true);
    }

}
```

Here is the SortedList class that I'm trying to create.

```
public class SortedList<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private List<T> _list;

    public List<T> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list = value; }
    }

    private Employee EmployeeComparer = new Employee();

    public SortedList()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }


    public void Insert(T item)
    {
        if (!_list.Contains(item))
        {
            _list.Add(item);
            Sort(_list);
        }
    }


    private void Sort(List<T> list)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);

        switch (type.Name)
        {
            case "Int32":
            case "String":
                list.Sort();
                break;

            case "Employee":
                Employee EmployeeComparer = new Employee();
                list.Sort(EmployeeComparer);
                break;

        }
    }


    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

From program.cs I'm basically populating the SortedList with three instances of Employee objects and I expect it to Sort it by employee's Name property and in the out put I expect to see this.

Barry

Neil

Zach

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SortedList<Employee> list = new SortedList<Employee>();
        list.Insert(new Employee() { Name="Zach"});
        list.Insert(new Employee() { Name = "Neil" });
        list.Insert(new Employee() { Name = "Barry" });


        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

    }
}
```

But I get a compiler error. It says:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ExtensingLists.Employee' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<T>'  ExtensingLists  C:\E Drive\VSProjects\C-Sharp Generics Course\ExtensingLists\ExtensingLists\SortedList.cs   57  Active
```

The error says line 57, which is this:

```
            list.Sort(EmployeeComparer);
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: List<T> does not have anything to ensure uniqueness. Thats another thing I'm trying to do here. But my question was around sorting. It can sort  value types without me telling it how. Some people suggest using Linq. but Linq's sort method returns another list. I actually wanted this list to be sorted everytime we do add/remove to it.

Comment: you are right. I overlooked the "Autosort" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List.Sort` method can be made to work in multiple ways.

> This method uses the default comparer Comparer.Default for type T to determine the order of list elements. The Comparer.Default property checks whether type T implements the IComparable generic interface and uses that implementation, if available. If not, Comparer.Default checks whether type T implements the IComparable interface. If type T does not implement either interface, Comparer.Default throws an InvalidOperationException.

So by making the below change, it will start working for you

```
public class Employee : IComparable<Employee> {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public int CompareTo(Employee other) {
        return string.Compare(Name, other.Name, true);
    }
}
```

and the Below change in `public class SortedList<T> : IEnumerable<T> {`

```
private static void Sort(List<T> list) {
    var type = typeof(T);
    list.Sort();
}
```

This is not the only way to do, but a preferable way to do when the Types are intrinsically `Orderable`. You can also use the `IComparer<T>` interface, but that is used when the Type needs to be sorted in a way that `IComparable<T>` does not or when the Type is not an `IComparable<T>`. I have listed all the code here together

```
class Program {

    static void Main() {
        SortedList<Employee> list = new SortedList<Employee>();
        list.Insert(new Employee() { Name = "Zach" });
        list.Insert(new Employee() { Name = "Neil" });
        list.Insert(new Employee() { Name = "Barry" });


        foreach (var item in list) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

    }
}

public class Employee : IComparable<Employee> {
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Age { get; set; }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public int CompareTo(Employee other) {
        return string.Compare(Name, other.Name, true);
    }
}


public class EmployeeAgeComparer : IComparer<Employee> {
    public int Compare(Employee x, Employee y) {
        return x.Age - y.Age;
    }
}

public class SortedList<T> : IEnumerable<T> {
    private List<T> _list;

    public List<T> List {
        get { return _list; }
        set { _list = value; }
    }

    private EmployeeAgeComparer EmployeeComparer = new EmployeeAgeComparer();

    public SortedList() {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }


    public void Insert(T item) {
        if (!_list.Contains(item)) {
            _list.Add(item);
            Sort(_list);
        }
    }

    private void Sort(List<T> list) {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Employee))
            list.Sort((IComparer<T>)EmployeeComparer);
        else
            list.Sort();
    }


    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vikram. for the explanation and solution.

Comment: Is there a way to use IComparer<T> to get it to work? Just curious.

Comment: @Vikram - Thanks for showing the other way of implementing IComparer<Employee>. I see now that you have used a cast (as as hvd was alluding to as well). Thank you again for detailed response. Very helpful!

Comment: @user5078178 You need the cast, since the argument to your `Sort` function is a `List<T>` and not a `List<Employee>`. Even if you type-check before invoke, the compiler cannot know this run-time information.

Answer (score 2):

The concrete question you're asking about is like asking why

```
int f(object o) { return o is int ? o : 0; }
```

fails to compile. Even if you've checked that `o` has type `int` at run-time, at compile-time it still has type `object`, which means it can't be used as the return value. You'd need a cast to get that working:

```
int f(object o) { return o is int ? (int)o : 0; }
```

and the same applies to your code.

But there's something more fundamentally wrong. Your `Employee` shouldn't be implementing `IComparer<Employee>`. It should be implementing [*`IComparable<Employee>`*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx), which specifies not that an `Employee` object knows how to compare two other `Employee` objects, but that it knows how to compare *itself* to another `Employee` object. And when you do that, you should be able to just call `list.Sort();` without checking the type at all.

Comment: Thank you. But intellisense of Sort() was telling me to pass something which implement IComparer<T> . Thats why I thought if Employee class implements IComparer<Employee> then it would work as I could pass a new Employee() as argument to Sort method of List.

Comment: @user5078178 Yes, *if* you want to pass in a comparer, you'd indeed need to implement `IComparer<Employee>` on some class. Commonly that would be done on a custom `EmployeeComparer` class, not on `Employee` directly. If you were to take that approach, that'd work fine too, as long as you include the cast like I mentioned. But after mentioning implementing `IComparable<Employee>`, I also mentioned to call `list.Sort();`, i.e. the overload that doesn't require a comparer. :)

Comment: Ok, That makes sense. So I should have created a new class called EmployeeComparer : IComparer<Employee> instead. Thank you.